# symfony 2 template inheritance and assets management in multi app environment

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I have a problem,

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_assetic_3625095_0" as such route does not exist.") in @base_templates/base.html.twig at line 9.
```

Sturcture of my app directory:

```
Resources // Contains common layouts and assets for all of my apps
config    // Contains common configs
current_app // yes, this is a current application directory
```

So. I have a base.html.twig in my Rosurces/views/ directory with such markup:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}"/>
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
    '@jquery'
    '@global' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And my current_app/Resources/views/base.html.twig inherit this Resources/views/base.html.twig

And I experience that problem I was talking about in the beginning.
Has anyone experienced such kind of problems already ? Do you have a solution ?
I know if I put javascripts code block inside my current_app/Resources/views/base.html.twig it works, but I need to keep common javascripts inside common layout. And I don't want to use symlink

Comment: Have you dumped your assetics and cleared cache? `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod` and `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: sure I did this, but don't need to do in dev environment